# On using sine and cosine substitutions in integration

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

When you make a substitution of the form $x=asin\theta$ for sines and cosines, shouldn't you check if the values of x on which we're integrating allows for it? Otherwise, if x becomes greater than |x|, wouldn't there be no possible values of $\theta$?

This is how it seems to work in cases like $\sqrt{9-x^2}$, where, it's obvious that you're safe with substituting $x=3 sin\theta$ or $x=3 
cos \theta$, since x can't go beyond |3|.

But I haven't heard of any explicit rule about this. Is there one, and if there isn't, why so?

Comment: +1 to your query - interesting question.  I can only give you my **informal experience**.  When attacking an integration problem that involves a trig substitution, I normally **pretend** that the problem is involving an indefinite rather than a definite integral.  Then, when I compute the antiderivative, I check for which range(s) of $x$ the antiderivative formula applies.  That is, having computed the antiderivative, I then see if the textbook deliberately set the upper and lower endpts of integrtn to make the formula valid.  This is the lazy way of doing it, but it works on textbk problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I=\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{4-t^2} dt $ is real and $t=2 \sin x$ works

but in $J=\int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{4-t^2} dt $ is imaginary here $t=2 \sin x$ will work again but you will get imaginary value.

Usually, we discard non-real answers.

Simililarly, in indefinite integration $K=\int \sqrt{4-t^2} dt$, we are supposed to avoid the substitution $t=3 \sin x$, because the integrand will become imaginary for $\sin x>2/3.$

Comment: This works for definite integration, great answer. I assume you meant that the integral from 2 onwards doesn't exist. How does it apply to indefinite integration, though? We wouldn't know the limits.

Comment: @Harry Holms You may see my answer where I have added some more stuff.

Comment: Right, got it. You can't just make any substitution, right?

Comment: Yes, first it will not help ans second it will invite non-real numbers, un-necessarily.